# C# - simulate keypress or keys to another application

Tags: c#, winforms, key, send, postmessage

I have a button on which I press it sends F5 to the application "Tibia". Tibia is not focused, and it sends the F5 in the background without a problem.

I wonder how can I send a string of text like "hello world".

Or send a CTRL+V. That way I could set my clipboard text to "hello world" first, and then send it.

It seems like I can only press 1 key at a time no matter what I do.

Please help me. Here's my code:

```
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Sends F5 to Tibia
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Tibia");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F5, 0);
        }
    }
```

Note: I do NOT want to focus on the Tibia window when I do this. It should be done "in the background" like now with the F5 press.

Comment: You need to `PostMessage` once for each letter in "hello world". To send multiple keys, try adding (or binary OR-ing) the keys together. This will only work with CTRL, ALT, and SHIFT keys I think, you can't send multiple alpha-numeric keys at once (like pressing the 'h' and 'e' key at the same time on your keyboard).

Comment: how would i post all letters? i tried doing  string text = "hello world"; foreach (char c in text) { //THIS IS WHERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE }

Comment: You would use another PostMessage for each key press (and key release!). You could hard code this as multiple lines of PostMessage, but I'd suggest iterating through an array of characters.

Comment: @aliazik you need to send the key codes, not the characters. Just like you are doing for F5 except for letters (`System.Windows.Forms.Keys.H` for example).

Comment: @Ron Beyer I'm pretty sure the ASCII codes (and therefore UNICODE codes) matches the key codes. It should be the same to pass `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.H` or `'h'`. (This only applies for character codes smaller than 128 of course which include all english letters.) But it may be more correct to use the key code constants of course.

Comment: @RobertS. They only match up for UPPERCASE characters (since a key, by itself, isn't uppercase or lower case). If he is sending Hello World by keys, the 'H' will work, but 'ello' will send a strange sequence of 'H', '5', (separator key x2) etc. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: @Ron Beyer: True. Using the key codes is by far a better approach. But for a simple program he might as well use `ToUpperCase()` then.